# sending image from imageview to local server

Tags: java, android

### Its a simple image-upload in android

i am using android to send image from my android emulator to server (my local machine)

---

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button submit;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new MainTest().execute();


            }
        });
    }



    /**
     * Method to post the image to the server.
     * U will have to change the url which will accept the image data.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public void postImageData() throws IOException
    {

        Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/Details/");
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "forest.jpg");
            reqEntity.addPart("key", bab);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //Log.v("Exception in Image", ""+e);
            reqEntity.addPart("key", new StringBody(""));
        }
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);       
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
    }

    public class MainTest extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                postImageData();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // data=jobj.toString();
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="135dp"
        android:layout_height="181dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Log**

```
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity.postImageData(MainActivity.java:97)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity$MainTest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:129)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity$MainTest.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-07 17:42:21.560: E/AndroidRuntime(345):  ... 4 more
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345): Activity com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f39ba0 that was originally added here
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@45f39ba0 that was originally added here
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity$MainTest.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:122)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at com.example.datapostingproject.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:70)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-07 17:42:23.700: E/WindowManager(345):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

How to resolve this ?

thanks

Comment: did you include your apache http library correctly? Your logcat says he can not find ByteArrayBody - Class

Comment: where to download that library ? .......... i have android mime , http mime jar packeges already

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/project-reports.html

But if this is not already include into your eclipse project, you should receive eclipse errors too.

Comment: Not sure if you can easily add that since Android already contains some parts of the [Apache Http](http://hc.apache.org/) implementation and it seems that this particular class is missing. Adding it might give funky conflicts.

Comment: Jar files i have ( android-support-v4.jar, apache-mime4j-0.6.jar, httpmime-4.0.1.jar ) re not sufficient ? ......thse i already have imported to my libs library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For correctly including external jars (like the Apache HttpMime) read this:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/jar-for-android/

Comment: I resolved adding jars but there is a new - problem ... ill post a new question for this !..... anyways thanks